# Google Sheets Script Sidebar button not activating function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sidebar, google-sheets-api

I've spent hours trying to figure this out, since I feel like I should do that before asking a question here. Searched, looked at answers, tried stuff. I think I learn that way and expand my skills/knowledge.

At any rate, I'm trying to just get started using a sidebar to make my sheets script app work better, and testing in small pieces. I want the Clear Old button (at this point) to simply open an alert box with the date in it, fed from a text box generated by [datePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Here is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
<body>
<p><strong>Clear Old Entries</strong></p>
          <p>Clear Entries before</p>
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Clear Old" onClick="google.script.run.ClearOld(document.getElementById(datepicker).value)" /></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Close Sidebar" onClick="google.script.host.close()" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the script code that gets the menu item and the sidebar, as well as the function I'm trying to use as a short term test:

```js
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Bulletinator')
      .addItem('Create Bulletin', 'bulletinatorSidebar')
      .addItem('Clear Old', 'clearOldSideBar')
      .addToUi();
}

function bulletinatorSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('BullV2Side')
      .setTitle('Bulletinator')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function clearOldSideBar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ClearOldSide')
      .setTitle('Clear Old Entries')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

var today;
var todayDay;
var todayDate;

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rg = sh.getDataRange();
var vA = rg.getValues();
var rowsFound = 0;
var rowsDeleted = 0;

function ClearOld(value) {
  var clearDate=value;
  var testThis = ui.alert(
 'Clear entries prior to',
 clearDate,
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

When I click the button in the sidebar there is no response, and nothing shows up in the execution transcript.

On a side note, I also struggled with being able to have two datePickers in the sidebar; only one worked. So that is why this setup has two separate sidebars getting called.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your html, `clearDate` is not defined. If you press F12 (to open your browser's console), you should see an error about this. Because an error is thrown here, your server script never gets called. You probably want `$("#datepicker").value`, i.e. the value of the datepicker input.

Comment: @tehhowch  I understand what you're saying but not clear how to make that happen. I put $("#datepicker").value inside the function call and that didn't work. Do I need  to escape my html and create a variable to that effect or something?

Comment: when I make calls like this I usually reference a client-side function, e.g. `onclick=myLocalCodeFn()` and then `function myLocalCodeFn() { /* setup and associated processing, like making an object of values to pass */ google.script.run....` I don't use jQuery much so that may be the wrong selector. I do know you want to pass the value of `document.getElementById(datepicker).value`, so use whatever works.

Comment: @tehhowch I changed the button code to <input type="submit" value="Clear Old" onClick="google.script.run.ClearOld(document.getElementById(datepicker).value)" /> and the console  is still saying cannot read 'value' of null. I'm not sure what I'm not  getting. I've learned a fair bit of Actionscript over the years, and have been able to adapt a lot of it to JavaScript but not sure where I'm off here.

Comment: So `ClearOldSide` in `ClearOldSideBar()` corresponds to html you provided, right?

Comment: @Carr That is correct. I've just this moment  found that I needed quotes around the (datepicker) value, so it needs to look like ("datepicker"). Now the console (which I'm only just learning to use) suggests that the data is feeding the function.

Comment: It works now. I'll edit my original post to show solution. This  took quite some time to get through this tiny bit, but it was worth it.

Comment: Everything is good now? So you could submit the correct value even you change the date value by datepicker?

Comment: Yes it works now. I am making a note of the syntax that worked. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, the `datepicker` variable is not defined. you have to use the next code

```
onClick="google.script.run.ClearOld(document.getElementById('datepicker').value)"
```

or

```
onClick="google.script.run.ClearOld($('#datepicker').val())"
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$('datepicker')` be `$('#datepicker')` ? just for chatting, never mind.